# Inputting values from CSV text file into arrays

Tags: c, arrays, csv

For some reason my program messes up in the first while loop but I really don't understand why. Yesterday I was using standard redirection input for stdin and I'm assuming opening a file is basically the same thing. Why is it not working now?

This is the text file I saved as '.csv' and which I'm opening:

hotdog, 10, 2, 1.50
bun, 10, 2, 0.50
burger, 100, 10, 2.00

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char command[25], str[100];
    int quantity[100], limit[100];
    double cost[100];
    char *item[100];
    char *token, *ptr;

    FILE *fp = fopen("inventory.csv", "rw");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        perror ("Error opening file");
    }

    //testing to see if program gets until here, then tries to copy data from CSV to arrays
    while(fgets(str, 100, fp) != NULL)
    {
        token = strtok (str,",");
        ptr = strdup(token);
        item[i] = ptr;
        sscanf (token, "%s", item[i]);
        token = strtok (NULL,",");
        sscanf (token, "%d", &quantity[i]);
        token = strtok (NULL,",");
        sscanf (token, "%d", &limit[i]);
        token = strtok (NULL,"\n");
        sscanf (token, "%lf", &cost[i]);
        i++;
    }

    printf("hey");

    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            printf("%s, %d, %d, %lf\n", item[j], quantity[j], limit[j], cost[j]);
        }

    strcpy(command, argv[1]);

    if(strcmp(command,"list") == 0)
    {
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            printf("%s, %d, %d, %lf\n", item[j], quantity[j], limit[j], cost[j]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("wtf hello");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're pointing fgets at stdin, not at the file you've just opened.

Comment: even once changing 'stdin' to 'fp', it still doesnt work

Comment: `item[i]` pointed to part of `str`.

Comment: How am I meant to store in item[i] exactly? This doesn't work either : `token = strtok (str,","); sscanf (token, "%s", item[i]);`

Comment: i copied token to another pointer before assigning item to that and now it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following statements for sscanf address of the entry should be given

sscanf (token, "%d", &quantity[i]);

sscanf (token, "%d", &limit[i]);

sscanf (token, "%lf", &cost[i]);

Comment: Thank you, that was my main mistake -_-